# How to use data from one JSON request for a second JSON request?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing, uitableview

I have been successful in parsing JSON from an API and displaying it in a tableview. The data I am receiving is a user's classes that he is enrolled in, however the data I am receiving is only the class Id's so I have to take each class ID and send a separate API request to get the class name and teacher. I am able to successfully do this on a separate view controller as I can get the class ID if the user clicks the row, however, I would like to display the class name and teacher and ID on a single table view.

So my question is, how would I get data from my table view and make a separate api request for each cell and display the data onto that cell?

My current data:

[image: What I have so far]

If I click a row I get this data:

```
2013-06-17 17:06:59.232 App[22024:c07] Class: Honors Pre-Calculus
2013-06-17 17:06:59.233 App[22024:c07] Teacher: Joe Shmo
```

How would I show both on one screen?

This is my code for retrieving class ids on first screen:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if ([searchResults count] == 0) {
    return [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
            NothingFoundCellIdentifier];



} else {

    ScheduleResultCell *cell = (ScheduleResultCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SearchResultCellIdentifier];

    ScheduleResult *searchResult = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    NSString *classFormat = @"%@";
    NSString *classfks = searchResult.class_fk;
    NSString *classfk = [NSString stringWithFormat:classFormat, classfks];

    cell.idLabel.text = classfk;

    return cell;

}
}
```

This is my code for retrieving class info on second screen:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://myapiurl.com/v1/classes/%@.json", idValue];

//show loader view
[SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Loading Info"];

//fetch the feed
_feed = [[ClassFeed alloc] initFromURLWithString:url
                                      completion:^(JSONModel *model, JSONModelError *err) {

                                          //hide the loader view
                                          [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

                                          //json fetched
                                          NSLog(@"Class: %@", _feed.course);
                                          NSLog(@"Teacher: %@", _feed.teacher_full_name);
                                          NSLog(@"Meeting Info: %@", _feed.meeting_times);

                                          [self.tableView reloadData];

                                      }];

}
```

Any idea how to accomplish this on one screen?

Here's what I've been trying to do, but it seems to only show data on one cell:

```
int count = [searchResults count];

    NSString *classFormat = @"%@";
    NSString *classfks = searchResult.class_fk;
    NSString *classfk = [NSString stringWithFormat:classFormat, classfks];

    for (int i=0; i < count; i++) {
        ScheduleResult *classInfo = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *classId = classInfo.class_fk;
        NSLog(@"i value: %d", i);
        url2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://apiurl.com/v1/classes/%@.json", classId];
        NSLog(@"url value: %@", url2);
        [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Loading Info"];
        _feed = [[ClassFeed alloc] initFromURLWithString:url2
                                              completion:^(JSONModel *model, JSONModelError *err) {

                                                  //hide the loader view
                                                  [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

                                                  //json fetched
                                                  NSLog(@"Class #%d: %@", i, _feed.course);
                                                  NSLog(@"Teacher #%d: %@", i,  _feed.teacher_full_name);
                                                  NSLog(@"Meeting #%d: %@", i,  _feed.meeting_times);
                                                  //name = namefk;
                                                  NSString *nameFormat = @"%@";
                                                  NSString *namefks = _feed.course;
                                                  NSString *namefk = [NSString stringWithFormat:nameFormat, namefks];
                                                  cell.nameLabel.text = namefk;

                                                  //[self.tableView reloadData];

                                              }];



                }
```

I tried adding my data to an array in an attempt at a different method but I can't even accomplish that correctly.

```
NSMutableArray* fullArray;
    fullArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [fullArray addObject:classfk];
    NSLog(@"array: %@", fullArray);
```

Debug output:

```
array: ( 10326
) 2013-06-17 23:36:45.488 App[30088:c07] array: ( 10371 ) 
2013-06-17 23:36:45.494 App[30088:c07] array: (
10420 )
```

If this question doesn't make much sense, I would like to ask how I can get the class_fk from this JSON feed (first url):

```
[{
    "class_fk": 10326,
    "currently_enrolled": true,
    "date_withdrawn": null,
    "enrollment_pk": 147745,
    "fee_paid": false,
    "late_date_enrolled": null,
    "level": null,
    "student_fk": 132664,
    "update_date": "2012-08-27"
},
{
    "class_fk": 10371,
    "currently_enrolled": true,
    "date_withdrawn": null,
    "enrollment_pk": 147168,
    "fee_paid": false,
    "late_date_enrolled": null,
    "level": null,
    "student_fk": 132664,
    "update_date": "2012-08-23"
}
```

And use it to insert into another url and get the course and teacher_full_name from this? (second url):

```
{
"class_id": "ADVMTG-40",
"class_pk": 10326,
"course": "Advisor Meeting",
"course_id": 7,
"course_type": "Advisory",
"description": "ADV: Shmo, J.",
"group_fk": 13980,
"primary_grade_level": "None",
"school_level": "Upper School",
"school_year": 2012,
"status": "Active",
"subject": "Administration",
"teacher_fk": 80404,
"teacher_full_name": "Joe Shmo",
"update_date": "2012-10-23T10:06:00-05:00",
"teachers": [
    {
        "person_fk": 80404,
        "role": "Primary Teacher",
        "role_id": 1,
        "teacher_name": "Joe Shmo",
        "update_grades": true,
        "view_grades": true
    }
],
"meeting_times": [
    {
        "block": "Advisor Meetings",
        "block_abbreviation": "ADV",
        "day": "Friday",
        "end_time": null,
        "grading_period": "ALL",
        "room": null,
        "start_time": null
    }
]}
```

Here is the solution to my problem (thanks so much for the help!):

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{



    //[searchResults sortUsingSelector:@selector(compareName:)];

    NSString *urlString = @"https://apiurl.com/v1/enrollments.json?student=132664";
    NSURL *Url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:Url];
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSArray *classes = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                       options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                         error:nil];
    //NSLog(@"classes array: %@", classes);

    //now we loop through all classes
    for (NSMutableDictionary *class in classes) {

        //we get individual data for each class

        NSString *classID = class[@"class_fk"];
        //NSLog(@"classID: %@", classID);
        NSString *classUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://apiurl.com/v1/classes/%@.json", classID];
        NSURL *classUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:classUrlString];
        NSURLRequest *classRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:classUrl];


        NSData *classData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:classRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil];
        NSDictionary *classDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:classData
                                                                        options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                                          error:nil];
        //NSLog(@"classes dictionary: %@", classDictionary);
        if (classes == nil) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self showNetworkError];
            });
            return;

        } else {
            if (classDictionary == nil) {
                NSLog(@"classes dictionary: %@", classDictionary);
            } else {
        //probably should check here if array is empty before accessing first object
        //we shove the data from a classDictionary into class
        //class[@"teacher_full_name"] = classDictionary[@"teacher"][0];

                if (classDictionary[@"teacher_full_name"] == nil) {
                    class[@"teacher_full_name"] = @"Not Provided";
                } else {
                    class[@"teacher_full_name"] = classDictionary[@"teacher_full_name"];
                }

                if (classDictionary[@"course"] == nil) {
                    class[@"course"] = @"Not Provided";
                } else {
                    class[@"course"] = classDictionary[@"course"];
                }

                if (classDictionary[@"class_pk"] == nil) {
                    class[@"class_pk"] = @"Not Provided";
                } else {
                    class[@"class_pk"] = classDictionary[@"class_pk"];
                }

                if (classDictionary[@"teachers"][0][@"person_fk"] == nil) {
                    class[@"person_fk"] = @"Not Provided";
                } else {
                 class[@"person_fk"] = classDictionary[@"teachers"][0][@"person_fk"];   
                }

        ScheduleResult *searchResult = [[ScheduleResult alloc] init];
        searchResult.name = class[@"course"];
        searchResult.teacher = class[@"teacher_full_name"];
        searchResult.class_fk = class[@"class_pk"];

        [searchResults addObject:searchResult];


        NSLog(@"searchresult: %@", class[@"person_fk"]);
        //NSLog(@"course: %@ and teacher: %@", class[@"course"], class[@"teacher_full_name"] );
            }
        }

    }



    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //NSLog(@"dictionary: %@", classes);
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    });
```

Comment: Literally the 3rd "iOS+JSON+UITableView" question today (at least).

Comment: Sorry, but I've spent days looking at other questions and I couldn't find one related to what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: I trust you and believe you. All of you did. Of course.

Comment: Thanks, hopefully I will get an answer because I've exhausted my brain this week trying to solve this.

Comment: What have you tried? You're able to fetch this feed and execute a completion block when it is retrieved. What do you imaging it would look like to fetch details on each feed entry in that completion block? Where would you store that data? How might you know when you are done and ready to dismiss your "loading" view?

Comment: I've tried many different for loops, but when I implement them it sends each request but there is no data returned. I've also tried storing the data in an array and trying to send a request based on each object in the array, but I can't get that to work. I am not sure about how it would look like. I assumed I would store the data in the cell's cell.nameLabel.text properties and then save the table as a whole in Core Data or in a plist. I thought the loading view would be dismissed after the completion.

Comment: @acenario the loop you describe is a reasonable place to start. Unfortunately since you didn't include that as an example I can't guess why it might not work as you expected. Can you present a more specific question? A vague general answer about creating model objects and managing a queue of updates to them doesn't seem like it would be useful to you at this point.

Comment: @Jonah I have edited and added the only thing that seems to kind of work. It loads the last cell and if I scroll to the bottom and then slowly scroll up it loads the other cells, but even then it doesn't really work.

Comment: @Jonah if that doesn't help, how would you suggest adding my tableview data into an array? Whenever I try to addobjects to the array it creates multiple instances of the array rather than creating a single array with all of the values? I have added my array code above and its results.

Comment: @Jonah I have also added a more definitive question to the bottom.

Comment: @acenario can you gimme first url you are hitting

Comment: @Hercules I cannot give you the first url as it is a private API but I posted the JSON response above for the first url and I posted the JSON response from the second URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok there's two options here.

First is (in a background queue), get the initial feed. Then parse the JSON. Then loop through the JSON and make api call for each dictionary in the array and shove it back into the dictionary. Then tell your table to reload on the main queue.

Second option is slightly more complicated. As the user scrolls through your table, you can make a call in a background queue to get the appropriate data and update the cell. It's very similar to how images are loaded asynchronously in a cell. Except here, it's not an image but rather JSON. You  should cache this data so this doesn't happen twice, and cancel the request if the user scrolls too quickly and the cell loading the data isn't on screen any more.

I suggest you stay with the first, keep it simple and easy (although maybe not as efficient because you are eager loading the data ahead of time, but if the # of records returned by the first api call is small, then it should be fine, but if it's in 100s then go with second option).

Also, it's important to note that you need to do all operations synchronously in the first option (that's how you know all data is downloaded).

Ok here's the first option. I did this with NSURLConnection. Please note that I don't like this option, but it's easy and gets the job done:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{

        //first we get all classes
        NSString *urlString = @"https://myapiurl.com/v1/classes";
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
        NSArray *classes = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                           options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                             error:nil];

        //now we loop through all classes
        for (NSMutableDictionary *class in classes) {

            //we get individual data for each class

            NSString *classID = class[@"class_fk"];
            NSString *classUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://apiurl.com/v1/classes/%@.json", classID];
            NSURL *classUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:classUrlString];
            NSURLRequest *classRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:classUrl];


            NSData *classData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:classRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil];
            NSDictionary *classDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:classData
                                                                            options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                                              error:nil];

            //probably should check here if array is empty before accessing first object
            //we shove the data from a classDictionary into class
            class[@"teachers_name"] = classDictionary[@"teachers"][0];
            class[@"course"] = classDictionary[@"course"];

        }

        //now you've got an array of dictionaries that have teachers name and course in it.
        //we tell our tableview to reload the data on main queue
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [someTableView reloadData];
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have two problems when trying your answer. I get the initial feed and parse the JSON but I am unable to add the data to an array (if you look above I posted my attempt at putting the data into an array). And suppose I do get it added to the array how would I shove back it into the dictionary?

Comment: @acenario check my updated answer. I don't know how your ClassFeed internally works so I can't comment on that.

Comment: @acenario in your code, where are you getting 'cell' from in line 'cell.nameLabel.text = namefk;' ?

Comment: I figured it out completely! Thanks so much. Last question, suppose I wanted person_pk out of teachers and block_abbreviation, how would I accomplish that using your code?

Comment: I think you mean person_fk. Just do it like I did with teachers_name, it's the same thing, just different keys.

Comment: Are you sure? person_fk is nested inside another array called teachers so I assumed you couldn't. I am getting an "object cannot be nil (key: person_fk)" error when I try.

Comment: yes, so look at what I did with teachers. classDictionary[@"teachers][0][@"person_fk"]. But you also have to do a nil check because there's no guarantee that it can't be nil. I suggest you try and understand the code and see what's going on first.

Comment: Okay I understand now, thanks so much for your help. I forgot how you implemented teacher_name because I changed your code to teacher_full_name because teacher_name sometimes reports nicknames. Also just implemented nil checks, should I post that code?

Comment: sure, i'll take a quick look

Comment: Okay added it to the end of the post. I added the whole thing.

Comment: Looks good. One thing though like I mentioned in the comments in your code, you should check if classDictionary[@"teachers"]'s count is bigger than 0, then do classDictionary[@"teachers"][0][@"blah blah"], otherwise it will crash your code if it's an empty array (just like assigning nil to a key in a dictionary). Also, unless i am a mistaken, you don't need to set networkActivityIndicatorVisible to NO. it will automatically do that. Also, you are calling showNetworkError part of the code too late. That should be moved outside/above the for loop. If classes is indeed nil, that nil check will...

Comment: never occur, because calling for loop on a nil object will never execute, so you will never get to that part of the code. Not to mention, it doesn't make any sense to be there.

Comment: hey guys please use chat instead.And remove un- useful comments after ending your discussion.